# How to save docx/txt/pdf or another types of files in database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I want to upload a file (like administrator) in SQL database and to display it on screen and than it maybe can be downloaded (by people),

I don't know from where to start and what to do.

So, my question is: How to save and see files with SQL databases using C#?

Comment: why not just saving the file path? why the file?

Comment: have you looked here? http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Download-files-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use filestreams. Have a look at https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XIm-8whRnYo

Comment: This is not helping me so much because I need function in C# not in SQL, because in SQL he is doing a thing but isn't the same in C#.